# Cannot get subcollection along with collection in flutter

Tags: flutter, future

I am trying to get documents with their own subcollections, from Stream, but I am stuck.

This is where I set up my StreamSubscription:

```
Future<void> _toggleOrdersHistorySubscription({FirebaseUser user}) async {
    _ordersHistorySubscription?.cancel();
    if (user != null) {
      _ordersHistorySubscription = ordersRepository
          .ordersHistoryStream(userId: user.uid)
          .listen((ordersSnapshot) {
        final List<OrderModel> tmpList = ordersSnapshot.documents.map((e) {
          // e.reference.collection("cart").getDocuments().;
          return OrderModel.orderFromSnapshot(e);
        }).toList();
        add(OrdersHistoryUpdated(ordersHistory: tmpList));
      });
    }
  }
```

The issue is that I can't see a way to get subcollection along with the parent document because getDocuments returns a Future.
Anyone can clear this issue for me?

---

So, I update the code method a separate method for retrieving data when listener is triggered but it doesn't work fully and I do not understand what's happening and why part of the code is working and part is not.

```
List<OrderModel> _getOrdersHistory({
    @required QuerySnapshot snapshot,
  }) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((document) {
          List<OrderedProductModel> cart = [];
          List<AddressModel> addresses = [];
          document.reference.collection("cart").getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
            snapshot?.documents?.forEach((doc) {
              cart.add(OrderedProductModel.fromSnapshot(doc));
            });
          });
          document.reference
              .collection("addresses")
              .getDocuments()
              .then((snapshot) {
            snapshot?.documents?.forEach((doc) {
              addresses.add(AddressModel.addressFromJson(doc.data));
            });
          });

          final order = OrderModel.orderFromSnapshot(
            document,
            restaurantCart: cart,
          );
          return order.copyWith(
            orderAddress:
                (addresses?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ? addresses.first : null,
            sentFromAddress:
                (addresses?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ? addresses.last : null,
          );
        })
            .toList() ??
        [];
  }
```

As an alternate solution to my original issue is that I made a map entry in Firestore instead of a collection for 2 address documents (which are set above as orderAddress and sentFromAddress) and for the cart I decided to get the data when needed for every cart item.

So the method which I put in the update is not the final one, but I want to understand what is happening up there as I do not understand why:

1. Why the cart is shown as empty if I do a print(order); right before the return and in the bloc it has data;
2. Why the orderAddress and sentFromAddress are both empty no matter what I try;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be short: You'll never be able to get a List synchronously if you get the data async from firebase.

Both questions have the same answer:

Your timeline:

1. For each document

   1. Create an empty list
   2. Initiate the firebase query - `getDocuments()`
   3. Subscribe to the returned future with - `.then((snapshot){cart.add(...)})`.
      This lambda will be invoked when the documents arrived.
   4. Another subscribe
   5. Save your empty `cart` and first/last of empty `addresses` to an `OrderModel`
2. Your List contains the references to your empty lists indirectly
3. Use your bloc, some time elapsed
4. Firebase done, your callbacks starts to fill up your lists.

Regarding your comment like stream.listen doesn't like async callbacks:
That's not true, you just have to know how [async functions work](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#execution-flow-with-async-and-await). They're run synchronously until the first await, then return with an incomplete future. If you do real async things you have to deal with the consequences of the time delay like changed environment or parallel running listeners.
You can deal with parallel running with `await for (T v in stream)` or you can use  [subscription.pause()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription/pause.html) and resume.

Answer (score 0):

If anything returns a future, just do this:

```
...getDocuments().then((value) => {
value is the item return here. Do something with it....
})
```

Also, you might want to split your method up a bit to share the responsibility.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for answering my question but it doesn't solve anything, I have tried it, but since getDocuments is asynchronous it goes out of scope before it finishes runing and I cannot get the data. 
I have updated my question with a more complex method.
What did you mean to split my method to share responsibility? You mean it's to big? It has only 11 lines of code and not even refactored.

Answer (score 0):

If `getDocuments` is a Future function and you need to wait for it, I think you should add `await` before it. I also don't see the snapshot status checking in your code pasted here. Maybe you have already checked the snapshot status in other function? Make sure the snapshot is ready when using it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering but it doesn't answer my issue.
The issue with awaiting getDocuments is that it needs to be inside an async method, from what I found out so far firebase listeners don't work well with async functions inside listen method.
I went with an alternate solution, save the adresses as Map in documents and with the cart I managed to make a solution just now.

Comment: From the last 2 questions you ask, I think because you use `then` but not `await`. `await` can make sure the line is complete before continue. If you use async method in sync function may cause the data is not ready when using it.

Comment: Though I still don't understand what do you mean `firebase listeners don't work well with async functions` and what is `part of the code is working and part is not`

Comment: I use the code inside bloc, from flutter_bloc. Last time I tried using something like stream.listen((snapshot) async {....... it didn't triggered the state, as far as I remember.